# Get separate lists based on object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I tried the below code but got an error.

```
<li>
  {items.map(item => 

    {item.status === 'active' ^^ <h1>{item.gender}</h1>}
    <p>{item.name}</p>
  }
<li>
```

I have my json like this:

```
[{"name":"james","satus":"active"},{"name":"alice","satus":"deactived"}]
```

The desired output is to separate the list-items by status heading. For example:

```
active
- james
- john
- mattew

deactive
- alice
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of getting the desired output would be to create two new arrays from your `items` array based on the `status`. *Note: you have a typo as "satus"*.

To do this you can use the [**Array.prototype.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjunction with the [**Array.prototype.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. Here's a demo:

```js
var Demo = React.createClass({
  _renderList: function(items, status) {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{status}</span>
        <ul>
          {items.filter(item => item.status == status).map((item, i) =>
            <li key={i}>{item.name}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  },
  
  render: function() {
    var items = [{"name":"james","status":"active"},{"name":"alice","status":"deactived"}];
    return (
      <div>
        {this._renderList(items, "active")}
        {this._renderList(items, "deactived")}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Imagine my list has lots of element like age, score, etc there will be lots of repeated code.

Comment: @AlexYong, so you want a new list for every unique property? Can you give an example?

Comment: ur example is working, that's exactly what I want, but can u move the duplicated code to a function?

Comment: @AlexYong, like that?

Comment: @AlexYong, did my answer solve your problem? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Quick sample below:

```js
const ListSample = () => {
  let items = [
      {"name":"James","status":"active"},
      {"name":"Alice","status":"deactived"},
      {"name":"John","status":"deactived"},
      {"name":"Joe","status":"active"},
      {"name":"Ann","status":"deactived"},
      {"name":"Jane","status":"active"}
  ];

  let statusList = [];
  for (let item of items) {
      if (statusList.indexOf(item.status) < 0) {
        statusList.push(item.status);
    }  
  }

  const renderList = (status) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{status}</h2>
        <ul>
          {
            items
              .filter(item => item.status === status)
              .map((item, i) => (<li key={i}>{item.name}</li>))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      { statusList.map(renderList) }
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<ListSample/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: imagine if I have other stuff than item.name, there will be many redundant code.

Comment: @AlexYong I refactored to be more easily extended and handle any number of statuses. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two `loops`, use two variables `active = [], deactived = []` and store the active and deactivated values in these and `return` them using a `div`, check the snippet:

```js
var a = [
           {"name":"james","status":"active"},
           {"name":"alice","status":"deactived"}
];

class App extends React.Component { 

    _createList() {
       let active = [], deactived = [];

       a.forEach((item,i) => {
         item.status === 'active'? active.push(<li key={i}>{item.name}</li>) : deactived.push(<li key={i}>{item.name}</li>); 
       })

       return(<div>
                 Active <ul> {active} </ul> 
                 Deactivated <ul> {deactived} </ul>
              </div>
       )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               {this._createList()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```